# python: try/except/else and continue statement

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why is the output of the below python code snippet *NOT* just **No exception:1**, since during first iteration there is no exception raised. From python docs (https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/errors.html).

> The try ... except statement has an optional else clause, which, when
>   present, must follow all except clauses. It is useful for code that
>   must be executed if the try clause does not raise an exception.

```
$ cat hello.py
for x in range(1,10):
  try:
    if x == 1:
        continue
    x/0
  except Exception:
    print "Kaput:%s" %(x)
  else:
    print "No exception:%s" %(x)
    break

$ python hello.py
  Kaput:2
  Kaput:3
  Kaput:4
  Kaput:5
  Kaput:6
  Kaput:7
  Kaput:8
  Kaput:9

 $ python -V
 Python 2.7.8
```

Comment: Please note my intent is not to get the code working. It is a toy example, I am more keen on knowing why the behaviour is not in line with what the tutorial docs says ? If there is a doc or python spec  explaining the reason for this behaviour please provide references to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tutorial gives a good start, but is not the language reference.  [Read the reference here.](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement)

Note in particular:

> The optional else clause is executed if and when control flows off the end of the try clause.

clarified by footnote 2:

> Currently, control “flows off the end” except in the case of an exception or the execution of a return, continue, or break statement.

So your use of `continue` is explicitly addressed by that.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a `continue`, so it never gets to the `else` block.  To achieve your result, you can not get to the `continue`:

**Code:**

```
for x in range(1, 10):
    try:
        if x != 1:
            x / 0
    except Exception:
        print "Kaput:%s" % (x)
    else:
        print "No exception:%s" % (x)
        break
```

**Result:**

```
No exception:1
```

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with your use of `continue` and `break`.  I think this is the functionality you're going for.  Basically, `continue` does not skip to the `else` statement, it continues on with the code (passed the try statement).  And, `break` breaks the for loop, thus producing no more output, so I removed that statement.

```
for x in range(1,10):
  try:
    if x != 1:
        x/0
  except Exception:
    print "Kaput:%s" %(x)
  else:
    print "No exception:%s" %(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the continue statement... its taking the control to for statement.. try removing the continue and add a conditional statement for x/0, like if(x!=1): x/0 then see the output you desire..